# Google Smart Home - Report State Real Time UI update

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have a question regarding report state and live updating in the app.

When I report a state from my server I expect to see changes in my thermostat without going to the main screen of the app and back into the thermostat. Now I have read many similar questions about this and I understand the app doesn't support updating the UI in real time with report state.

I also followed the codelabs tutorial on implementing a smart home action (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer/#0). With this implementation the UI updates as soon as report state is called, which is what I would expect.

Essentialy what I have done is just modify the codelabs example to work with express, and changed the washer to a thermostat. Also the report state returns status code 200.

So how come the UI is updated when using the demo implementation from codelabs, but not when I use my implementation? The code from codelabs runs on firebase while mine runs on an express instance on my laptop, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Does your implementation work if you're keeping the washer and washer traits?

Comment: Same problem here. Report State doesn't update the app in the realtime.

Comment: @NickFelker Now I have tried rewriting the codelabs test app (with the washer) to use express and it works as you said. Any insights on what is happening here?

Comment: Maybe it's something that only happens for washers but nothing else?

Comment: @NickFelker where could I report this issue with the app?

Comment: The smart home issue tracker is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).

Answer (score 0):

Google Home App depends on various components for updating the state in the UI, including query and report state responses. You should make sure that you are able to respond to queries successfully as well as doing report state.
You can make sure both your report state and query responses are functional by using [Test Suite](https://developers.home.google.com/tools/test-suite). In case your report states are shown as having errors there, you can also use the [Home Graph Viewer](https://developers.home.google.com/tools/home-graph-viewer) to see the states of your devices in Homegraph.