# Google Smart Home App doesn't update the state of the device in the real time after Report State request. Is that expected?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141669/google-smart-home-report-state-real-time-ui-update), but it doesn't answer my question - 
does Google Home App supports real time updates from the [Report State](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state) requests?

I searched everywhere and didn't find the answer. Neither documentation or app says anything about that. My requests are accepted by home graph API, but state of the device in the app not updated in the real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the Google Home app does not update the state in realtime. If you close and open the app, you should see the state change.

If you call the Report State API and get a `200` response code, then you've done it right.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Just wanted to know if I do everything right. As this is not stated anywhere and in 2020 I expected real time updates :) by default.